# Getting information about a query from introspection tab graphql

Tags: graphql

I was wondering if there was a way of getting the parameters required for a certain query from the introspection __schema.

For example, I can get all aveilable queries of a certain graphQL with:

```
__schema{
    queryType{
        fields{
            name
            description
        }
    }
}
```

Or all aveilable types with

```
__schema{
    types{
        name
        kind
        description
    }
}
```

Is it there a way to get the parameters of a certain query from the introspection? For example, I want to know which parameters I need for getting info from a certain query (Lets name it allPages).

Something like

```
query{
    allPages{
        id
        name
        page{
            id
            description
            whatever
        }
    }
}
```